# Updating multiple columns for each record from table with multiple records for each ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is my first time posting a question here so please be gentle, I searched as exhaustively as I could. Sometimes it's how to search for the answer that is half the battle.

What I'm trying to do is update Table 1 with the data from Table 2 for each person for each period. Some people will have category A,B, and/or C records in Table 2, but not all and not necessarily all three.

The problem I'm running into is that my statement I'm using to do the update will update some of the columns but not all. I'm guessing this is because the updates weren't committed yet while doing the update so it can't fetch values that haven't been committed yet.

Do I need to do 3 separate update statements or can this somehow be handled through a case statement. I'm looking for most efficient methods here. Updating Table 1 who has 2 million records for each period.

Table 1 - Period_Perf

```
CustID
Period_Date
Perf_Cat_A
Perf_Cat_B
Perf_Cat_C
```

Table 2 - Period_Perf_Detail

```
CustID
Period_Date
Perf_Category (will contain A, B, or C)
Perf_Points (will contain a integer value)
```

Here's essentially the statement I've been trying to use:

```
UPDATE
 Period_Perf
SET
Perf_Cat_A = CASE WHEN pd.Perf_Category = 'A' then pd.Total_Perf_Points else Perf_Cat_A END
 Perf_Cat_B = CASE WHEN pd.Perf_Category = 'B' then pd.Total_Perf_Points else Perf_Cat_B END
 Perf_Cat_C = CASE WHEN pd.Perf_Category = 'C' then pd.Total_Perf_Points else Perf_Cat_C END
from
 Period_Perf
ON
INNER JOIN
(
 select
 CustID
 ,Period_Date
 ,Perf_Category
 ,sum(Perf_Points) as Total_Perf_Points
 from
 Period_Perf_Detail
 group by CustID, Period_Date, Perf_Category
) as pd
ON
 Period_Perf.CustID = pd.CustID and Period_Perf.Period_Date = pd.Period_Date
```

Comment: The problem you have here is that the Perf_Cat_A, B and C will be updated all at the same time, from one of the rows from pd -select -- so if there's more than one row there, you won't get separate updates to different columns

Comment: I was suspicious that might be the case. Was hoping there was a trick instead of using three separate update statements. Thanks again! (btw, how did you get the code snippet formatted so nicely for me? I was trying to figure out how to do that)

Comment: You'll get the code either by indenting with 4 spaces, or there's also a button above the edit box that says "Code sample"

Answer (score 0):

To update all the values at once, you'll need to have data that has all those three values in one row, so something like this:

```
UPDATE P
SET
    Perf_Cat_A = pd.Cat_A,
    Perf_Cat_B = pd.Cat_B,
    Perf_Cat_C = pd.Cat_C
from
Period_Perf P
cross apply (
  select
    sum(case when Perf_Category = 'A' then Perf_Points else 0 end) as Cat_A,
    sum(case when Perf_Category = 'B' then Perf_Points else 0 end) as Cat_B,
    sum(case when Perf_Category = 'C' then Perf_Points else 0 end) as Cat_C
  from 
    Period_Perf_Detail D
  where
    D.CustID = P.CustID and 
    D.Period_Date = P.Period_Date
) as pd
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully there's no bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT statements first to understand your data, then build an update based on that select statement.

First use the following query to better understand why your update statement is not producing your desired results.

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN pd.Perf_Category = 'A' THEN pd.Total_Perf_Points ELSE Perf_Cat_A END AS Perf_Cat_A
        , CASE WHEN pd.Perf_Category = 'B' THEN pd.Total_Perf_Points ELSE Perf_Cat_B END AS Perf_Cat_B
        , CASE WHEN pd.Perf_Category = 'C' THEN pd.Total_Perf_Points ELSE Perf_Cat_C END AS Perf_Cat_C
FROM      Period_Perf
ON
          INNER JOIN
                    (
                              SELECT    CustID
                                      , Period_Date
                                      , Perf_Category
                                      , SUM(Perf_Points) AS Total_Perf_Points
                              FROM      Period_Perf_Detail
                              GROUP BY  CustID
                                      , Period_Date
                                      , Perf_Category ) AS pd
          ON        Period_Perf.CustID          = pd.CustID
                    AND Period_Perf.Period_Date = pd.Period_Date
```

I suggest the following query for your update.

```
UPDATE Period_Perf
SET       Perf_Cat_A = SUM(a.Perf_Points) 
        , Perf_Cat_B = SUM(b.Perf_Points) 
        , Perf_Cat_C = SUM(c.Perf_Points) 
FROM      Period_Perf
          LEFT JOIN Period_Perf_Detail AS a
          ON        Period_Perf.CustID      = a.CustID
                AND Period_Perf.Period_Date = a.Period_Date
                AND a.Perf_Category = 'A'
          LEFT JOIN Period_Perf_Detail AS b
          ON        Period_Perf.CustID      = b.CustID
                AND Period_Perf.Period_Date = b.Period_Date
                AND a.Perf_Category = 'B'
          LEFT JOIN Period_Perf_Detail AS c
          ON        Period_Perf.CustID      = c.CustID
                AND Period_Perf.Period_Date = c.Period_Date
                AND a.Perf_Category = 'C'
GROUP BY Period_Perf.CustID , Period_Perf.Period_Date
```

Please notice that instead putting criteria in a WHERE, it is in the join itself. This way you don't affect the entire dataset, but just the subsets individually on each join.